# Is 1 Thessalonians 3:11 an example of Granville Sharp's rule?

Tags: grammar, 1-thessalonians, granville-sharp

> Now may our God and Father himself, and our Lord Jesus, direct our way to you (1 Thessalonians 3:11 ESV)
> αὐτὸς δὲ ὁ θεὸς καὶ πατὴρ ἡμῶν καὶ ὁ κύριος ἡμῶν Ἰησοῦς κατευθύναι τὴν ὁδὸν ἡμῶν πρὸς ὑμᾶς

The phrase translated as *our God and Father* is ὁ θεὸς καὶ πατὴρ ἡμῶν having the TSKS format which, according to Sharp's Rule is speaking of one. In this case God and Father are two attributes describing one.

Is 1 Thessalonians 3:11 an example of Granville Sharp's rule?

Comment: Yes. 'The God and Father' is a TSKS construction - 'the'/substantive/ _kai_ /substantive - and therefore the two substantives, 'bracketed' by the article, refer to one person. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daniel Wallace has set out the very strict rules required for the "Granville Sharp" rule to apply.  To remove confusion among Sharp's six rules, Wallace gives this grammatical construction the name, "TSKS" (Greek Grammar Beyond the Basics, page, 270ff).  Further, Wallace also reports that extensive surveys amongst the Koine Greek literature generally, found no exception to this TSKS rule.

The very strict rules for this rule (as enumerated by Wallace) are:

- article-substantive-kia-substantive sequence
- the substantives are personal nouns (usually titles or attributes)
- the substantives are singular and not plural
- neither substantive is impersonal
- neither is a proper name
- both substantives must be in the same grammatical case

Under these conditions, when all of the above applies, then ***both substantives apply to the same person***.

Wallace then lists many examples of this (not exhaustively) in the NT Koine Greek.  His list does not include the excellent example of 1 Thess 3:11 which reads:

- ὁ Θεὸς καὶ Πατὴρ ἡμῶν
- the God and Father of us

Note that this fulfills all the requirements of the TSKS rule namely

- it has article-substantive-kia-substantive sequence
- the substantives, "God" and "Father" are personal titles and not names
- the substantives are singular and not plural
- neither substantive is impersonal
- neither is a proper name.
- both are in the same grammatical case, namely (in this instance), nominative

Therefore, "God" and "Father" both refer to the same person, namely, God the Father in this case.  Paul (and others) is rather fond of this construction and uses it regularly:

- Rom 15:6 - so that with one accord, with one mouth, you may glorify **the God and Father** of our Lord Jesus Christ.
- 1 Cor 15:24 - Then the end will come, when He hands over the kingdom to **[the] God the Father** after He has destroyed all dominion, authority, and power.
- 2 Cor 11:31 - **The God and Father** of the Lord Jesus, the One being blessed to the ages, knows that I am not lying.
- Eph 1:3 - Blessed be **the God and Father** of our Lord Jesus Christ, the One according to His great mercy having begotten us again to a living hope, through the resurrection of Jesus Christ out from the dead,
- Eph 5:20 - giving thanks at all times for all things in the name of our Lord Jesus Christ to **the God and Father**.
- 1 Thess 1:3 - and continually recalling before **the God and Father of us** your work of faith, your labor of love, and your enduring hope in our Lord Jesus Christ.
- 1 Thess 3:11 - Now may **the God and Father of us** Himself, and our Lord Jesus, direct our way to you.
- 1 Thess 3:13 - so that He may establish your hearts in blamelessness and holiness before **the God and Father of us** at the coming of our Lord Jesus with all His saints. Amen.
- 1 Peter 1:3 - Blessed be **the God and Father** of our Lord Jesus Christ! By His great mercy He has given us new birth into a living hope through the resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead,
- James 1:27 - Pure and undefiled religion before **the God and Father** is this: to visit orphans and widows in their tribulation; to keep oneself unstained from the world.
- Rev 1:6 - who has made us to be a kingdom, priests to **the God and Father** of Him—to Him be the glory and power forever and ever! Amen.

This list is not exhaustive, but only a sample.